# Formular for partial gradient of multi-variable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, neural-networks

Is there a property of gradient that allow me to compute $\partial f/\partial x$ with $f=f(x, y, z)$ and $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$.Can we write that $\partial f/\partial x = \partial f/\partial y * \partial y / \partial x + \partial f/\partial z *\partial z / \partial x$ or something like that. I came upon this question when trying to understand the backpropagation equation of recurrent neural network and I don't understand while it sum all the partial gradient through time.

Comment: Example: see if this helps ... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481247/chain-rule-for-partial-derivatives ..

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a function of $(x,y,z)$ and $(y,z)$ are themselves functions of $x$, then $f$ can be rewritten so that it is a function of $x$ alone. Let's call the single-variable function $\phi(x)$.

So there are two distinct quantities which one might call the derivative (gradient) of the function  wrt $x$
$$\eqalign{
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cr
{\rm -or-} \cr
&\frac{d\phi}{dx}
 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} 
 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}
 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{dz}{dx}
}$$
where $\partial$ has been used for the partial derivative of multi-variable functions, and $d$ for the derivative of a single-variable function.